# React.createElement pass props to children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component A which gets a component B and renders it as a child component.

I'm rendering component A with [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
React.createElement(A, A_props, [B]);
```

I want to pass component B some props, how can I do that?

Unfortunately, I can not use JSX..

Comment: Just clone the element and pass the props you want like this? `React.createElement(A, A_props, React.cloneElement(B, { someProp: 'someVal' }))`. If that works for you I can write it up as an answer :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Works like a magic!
Yes, I would like it to be an answer. Can you please elaborate why didn't you set `React.cloneElement(B, { someProp: 'someVal' })` in an array?

Comment: Well you only have one child, if you need more than one it would be an array. probably best to keep array for consistency though :) [**Here's a decent resource on passing a single child or many**](https://learn.co/lessons/react-create-element#becoming-a-parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a parent if you arent creating the element there but just passing the child through as a reference then you would want to clone it and throw whatever props you want through then. That would look something like this

```
const clonedBElem = React.cloneElement(B, { someProp: 'someVal' })
React.createElement(A, A_props, [clonedBElem])
```